# How-to write a password-safe class?

Tags: c++, string, memory

This question follows a suggestion made by @sharptooth in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785366/how-to-ensure-that-compiler-optimizations-dont-introduce-a-security-risk).

Can `std::string` be tweaked so that it becomes password-safe ?

If not, what would be the guidelines to write a password-handling class (thus a class that takes big care about what it writes to memory and clears it before destruction) ?

Comment: 1) use std:wstring, 2) push 0x2022 in instead of password symbols :o) Seriously, if you fear that other process sniffs something from your memory, add/remove some mask to it (xor?)

Comment: @alxx: How would using `std::wstring` instead of `std::string` be safer ?! Am I missing something ?

Comment: 0x2022 is bullet symbol. Get it? :)

Comment: @alxx: Ok, I finally get the joke ;) Ciphering the strings in memory doesn't help much: if I cipher my strings, both my cipher key and cipher algorithm will be in memory as well. I'm really looking for guidelines to ensure that memory is not copied around too much and automatically reset before destruction.

Comment: @alxx: using wstring is unnecessary, you can push `"\xe2\x80\xa2"` into `std::string`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, first define a custom allocator:

```
template <class T> class SecureAllocator : public std::allocator<T>
{
public:
    template<class U> struct rebind { typedef SecureAllocator<U> other; };

    SecureAllocator() throw() {}
    SecureAllocator(const SecureAllocator&) throw() {}
    template <class U> SecureAllocator(const SecureAllocator<U>&) throw() {}

    void deallocate(pointer p, size_type n)
    {
        std::fill_n((volatile char*)p, n*sizeof(T), 0);
        std::allocator<T>::deallocate(p, n);
    }
};
```

This allocator zeros the memory before deallocating. Now you typedef:

```
typedef std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, SecureAllocator<char>> SecureString;
```

However there is a small problem, std::string may use small string optimization and store some data inside itself, without dynamic allocation. So you must explicitly clear it on destruction or allocate on the heap with our custom allocator:

```
int main(int, char**)
{
    using boost::shared_ptr;
    using boost::allocate_shared;
    shared_ptr<SecureString> str = allocate_shared<SecureString>(SecureAllocator<SecureString>(), "aaa");

}
```

This guarantees that all the data is zeroed before deallocation, **including** the size of the string, for example.

Comment: Don't use `std::fill_n`, use something like `SecureZeroMemory()` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366877(VS.85).aspx) - with `std::fill_n` the compiler might optimize the erasing away.

Comment: Also is there a tweak to force `std::string` erase the space when the calling code causes the string to be shortened - for example removes first N elements and so the tail is moved "leftwards" and leaves characters "on the right"?

Comment: @sharptooth SecureZeroMemory is not standard, and volatile prevents optimization. Yes, if there is no system call some data may remain in memory before the CPU flushes the cache.

Comment: @ybungalobill: Not sure, but looks like a neat way of using `volatile` for good.

Comment: @sharptooth in C++0x there is shrink_to_fit, however it's not binding request. To force shrinking you can do a copy and swap. (Well, this also won't work with reference counted string... so I guess that you can't do it with string. You **can** do it with vector, since it destructs the elements, so you need to zero the memory in SecureAllocator::destroy too).

Comment: @ybungalobill: Thanks for this complete answer. Would you mind adding a non-boost version of the last code sample ? Using boost where I work is *sadly* not an option... I can use `tr1::shared_ptr` thought.

Comment: @ereOn you can use tr1::shared_ptr with custom deleter. std::allocate_shared is going to be included in C++0x.

Comment: @ybungalobill: congratz on your first K :-)

Comment: Well, if one takes a peak into the respective library-implementation, one could replace the destructor for that template-instantiation, with a version first doing what a non-modified version would do (free with the secure allocator), and then overwriting the string-object itself. Thereafter no need for the smart-pointer...

Comment: The allocator should disable swapping of the page it allocates memory in by calling [`mlock`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlock.2.html). Otherwise the data may be written to disk.