# Does using "pointer to volatile" prevent compiler optimizations at all times?

Tags: c++, volatile

Here's the problem: [your program temporarily uses some sensitive data and wants to erase it when it's no longer needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785366/how-to-ensure-that-compiler-optimizations-dont-introduce-a-security-risk). Using `std::fill()` on itself won't always help - the compiler might decide that *the memory block is not accessed later, so erasing it is a waste of time* and eliminate erasing code.

[User ybungalobill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/277176/ybungalobill) suggests [using `volatile` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785582/how-to-write-a-password-safe-class/3785676#3785676):

```
{
  char buffer[size];
  //obtain and use password
  std::fill_n( (volatile char*)buffer, size, 0);
}
```

The intent is that upon seeing the `volatile` keyword the compiler will not try to eliminate the call to `std::fill_n()`.

Will `volatile` keyword always prevent the compiler from such memory modifying code elimination?

Comment: Hmmm, I think that it's not the exact situation. Here the compiler knows that the memory is allocated on stack, there it doesn't. (so it may point to a memory mapped register)

Comment: I was about to post a similar question regarding this answer. Funny how one concern can raise a lot of other interesting questions ;) Here is my +1.

Comment: Try declaring the buffer as `volatile char buffer[size];` rather than casting it in the call to `std::fill_n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is free to optimize your code out *because `buffer` is not a volatile object*.

The Standard only requires a compiler to strictly adhere to semantics for volatile objects. Here is what C++03 says

> The least requirements on a conforming implementation are:
>
> - At sequence points, volatile objects are stable in the sense that previous evaluations are complete and
>     subsequent evaluations have not yet occurred.
>     [...]

and

> The observable behavior of the abstract machine is its sequence of reads and writes to volatile data and
>   calls to library I/O functions

In your example, what you have are reads and writes using volatile lvalues to non-volatile objects. C++0x removed the second text I quoted above, because it's redundant. C++0x just says

> The least requirements on a conforming implementation are:
>
> - Access to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine.[...]
>
> These collectively are referred to as the *observable behavior* of the program.

While one may argue that "volatile data" could maybe mean "data accessed by volatile lvalues", which would still be quite a stretch, the C++0x wording removed all doubts about your code and clearly allows implementations to optimize it away.

But as people pointed out to me, It probably does not matter in practice. A compiler that optimizes such a thing will most probably go against the programmers intention (why would someone have a pointer to volatile otherwise) and so would probably contain a bug. Still, I have experienced compiler vendors that cited these paragraphs when they were faced with bugreports about their over-aggressive optimizations. In the end, `volatile` is inherent platform specific and you are supposed to double check the result anyway.

Comment: _Why these rules tend to be playing with words?

Answer (score 3):

From the last C++0x draft [intro.execution]:

> 8 The least requirements on a
>   conforming implementation are:
>
> — Access to volatile objects are
>   evaluated strictly according to the
>   rules of the abstract machine.
>
> [...]
>
> 12 Accessing an object designated by a
>   volatile glvalue (3.10), modifying an
>   object, calling a library I/O
>   function, or calling a function that
>   does any of those operations are all
>   side effects, [...]

So even the code you provided must not be optimized.

Comment: At least, the side-effects of writing to volatile objects must not be removed under the as-if rule, which means that the code does what it should. The compiler is still free to perform other optimizations in `fill_n`, such as loop unrolling, or assembler peephole optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

The memory content you wish to remove may have already been flushed out from your CPU/core's inner cache to RAM, where other CPUs can continue to see it.  After overwriting it, you need to use a mutex / memory barrier instruction / atomic operation or something to trigger a sync with other cores.  In practice, your compiler will probably do this before calling any external functions (google Dave Butenhof's post on volatile's dubious utility in multi-threading), so if you thread does that soon afterwards anyway then it's not a major issue.  Summarily: volatile isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

A conforming implementation may, at its leisure, defer the actual performance of any volatile reads and writes until the result of a volatile read would affect the execution of a volatile write or I/O operation.

For example, given something like:

```
volatile unsigned char vol1,vol2;
extern unsigned char res[1000];
void test(int scale)
{
  unsigned char ch;

  for (int 0=0; i<10000; i++)
  {
    res[i] = i*vol1*scale;
    vol2 = res[i];
  }
}
```

a conforming compiler could, at its option, check whether `scale` is a multiple of 128 and--if so--clear out all even-indexed values of `res` before doing any reads from `vol1` or writes to `vol2`.  Even though the compiler would need to do each reads from `vol1` before it could do the following write to `vol2`, a compiler may be able to defer both operations until after it has run an essentially unlimited amount of code.