# Zeroing memory without optimization

Tags: c++

As you know, we cannot use `memset()` for zeroing a memory **if it is not accessed later** because it may be optimized by compiler. I saw a suggestion in cpp ref that we can use `std::fill` with a **`volatile`** pointer to solve this problem. Now here are my questions:

1. Does this statement means if the pointer is not `volatile`, `std::fill` may be optimized too?
2. How we can get a volatile pointer to a container, for example `vector`? Does something like this work?

```
vector<int> v;
volatile auto ptr = v.data();
```

Comment: If the memory is not accessed, why set it to zeroes anyway?

Comment: @Devolus There are a lot of reasons. A common one is **security**. For example, you need to zero an encryption key when you don't need it anymore to prevent dumping key from memory.

Comment: You may consider using a customer memory allocator

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785798/does-using-pointer-to-volatile-prevent-compiler-optimizations-at-all-times

Comment: @DavidBien Thanks for topic, but it only answers first question and it does not say anything about 2nd part.

Comment: Consider using `gsl::ensures` or like something. https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/blob/main/include/gsl/assert#L129

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935190/why-is-a-point-to-volatile-pointer-like-volatile-int-p-useful and yes, obtaining a volatile pointer to a vector's data should be enough to ensure that that vector is not optimized out - unless of course the method in which you obtain that pointer is somehow optimized out... :-P

Comment: *"but it only answers first question"*, that's why it should be one question by question only.

Comment: Notice that `volatile auto ptr = v.data();` results in `int* volatile` and not to `int volatile*` (or `volatile int*`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this will work:

```
volatile int* ptr = vec.data();
std::fill(ptr, ptr+vec.size(), 0);
```

The one thing that prevents the compiler from optimizating it away is the `volatile` keyword (this is basically the whole purpose of that keyword), so std::fill with a non-volatile pointer will also be optimized.

Since memset is defined to take a non-volatile pointer, it can be optimized away even if you pass a volatile pointer to it (in which case you will also need the `-fpermissive` flag to allow the compiler to convert the volatile pointer to a non-volatile pointer - otherwise it will not compile).

I made a small example of the possibilities, which makes it quite visible: https://godbolt.org/z/xqYG1Ksod
(Note that I used a raw array instead of a vector, as the vector constructor would otherwise add more unrelated noise to the asm output).

Comment: From a comment by Jarod42 above: Notice that `volatile auto ptr = v.data();` results in `int* volatile` and not to `int volatile*` (or `volatile int*`).

Comment: @interjay: Thanks, I updated the answer (not a big fan of auto anyway, only used it because it was used in the question)

Comment: From linked question, compilers are free to optimize as source is not really `volatile`.