# Memset memory that will not be optimized away

Tags: c, buffer, memset

This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66980425/8913338): is there is a way to memset a buffer after finished using it (for security for example) without it being optimized out?

Trying to cast the pointer to volatile pointer getting warning about sending volatile pointer to function that not expects volatile.

Comment: Are you looking for `memset_explicit()`?

Comment: If your standard library does not include `memset_explicit()` yet (it is in the draft C23 standard), you could use [Gnulib](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/) to provide it. It implements it in various ways, depending on the compiler and library.

Comment: Thanks for the referenc to memset_explicit(), I wasn't aware to it. Unfortunately, my standard library not support it.

Comment: Just overwrite the memory area yourself with zeroes using a loop and a volatile pointer. Assuming it is not performance critical and large, just writing byte by byte should be fine, but an optimized version could write most of it using 64 bit integer instead of char.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `memset_explicit()` function from the C23 draft standard does what you want, but might not be implemented in current versions of the C standard library. The GNU [Gnulib](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/) (GNU Portability Library) includes a version of `memset_explicit()` that can be incorporated in a project's sources under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License. The initial import into a project assumes that the project uses Autoconf, so that could be a problem for projects that do not use Autoconf.

The Gnulib [implementation of `memset_explicit()`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=gnulib.git;a=blob_plain;f=lib/memset_explicit.c;hb=refs/heads/stable-202301) uses conditional compilation to implement the function in various ways, such as calling `memset_s()` (if available), adding a memory barrier after a call to `memset()`, or if none of those can be used, calling `memset()` via a volatile function pointer. The use of a volatile function pointer involves defining and initializing a function pointer `volatile_memset` like this:

```
    void * (* const volatile volatile_memset) (void *, int, size_t) = memset;
```

Calls to `memset()` through the `volatile_memset` pointer will not be optimized away.

Comment: Thanks, looks good. I suppose there is yet little down side here that the compiler can't optimize it in cases of short buffer to inline mem-setting.

Answer (score 0):

A fully portable version from C90 to C23 is to use a struct wrapper and then declare a `volatile` struct object:

```
typedef struct
{
  uint8_t buf [n];
} buf_t;


volatile buf_t buf = {0}; 
// equivalent to memset(buf, 0, sizeof buf) but can't be optimized out
...
static const buf_t final_settings = { ... }; 
// some values you wish the buffer to have in the end
...
buf = final_settings; 
// equivalent to memset/memcpy but can't be optimized out
```

This also dodges the quirk/flaw in C regarding "access of volatile object" vs "volatile lvalue access" (also fixed in C23).

Comment: What with the case that the buffer size not known in compile time?

Comment: Can we replace buf = final_settings; by buf = (buf_t){0};?

Comment: @arye "What with the case that the buffer size not known in compile time?"  You didn't mention that as a requirement in the question.  "Can we replace buf = final_settings; by buf = (buf_t){0};?"  Yes.

Comment: I upvoted the answer, but still waiting to see if someone will have more general and clean solution