# Secure deallocation of boost::asio::const_buffer

Tags: c++, security, boost, pci-dss

For the purpose of PA:DSS I need to be sure that boost::asio::const_buffer (e.g. in boost::asio::async_write) will be zeroed when coming out of scope.

With a STL containers I can substitute a allocator/deallocator like this:

```
    void deallocate(volatile pointer p, size_type n) {
        std::memset(p, 0, n * sizeof(T));
        ::operator delete(p);
    }
```

However I have no idea how to achieve the same with boost::asio::const_buffer, at least not in a way which would still let boost::asio::async_write to consume it. Also I don't want to reinvent the wheel (if there is any).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: *Asio buffers don't own their memory, so they should not be responsible for disposing of it either*.

First off, you should **not** use

```
std::memset(p, 0, n * sizeof(T));
```

Use a function like [`SecureZeroMemory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366877(v=vs.85).aspx) instead: [How-to ensure that compiler optimizations don't introduce a security risk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785366/how-to-ensure-that-compiler-optimizations-dont-introduce-a-security-risk/3785388#3785388)

I realize you had `volatile` there for this reason, but it might not always be honoured like you expect:

> Your `secure_memset` function might not be sufficient. According to http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1381.pdf there are optimizing compilers that will only zero the first byte [–  Daniel Trebbien Nov 9 '12 at 12:50](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973260/what-is-the-correct-way-to-clear-sensitive-data-from-memory-in-ios#comment18150466_9978284)

Background reading:

- https://cryptocoding.net/index.php/Coding_rules#Clean_memory_of_secret_data
- http://blog.quarkslab.com/a-glance-at-compiler-internals-keep-my-memset.html

---

### On to ASIO

Make sure you fully realize that Boost Asio buffers ***have no ownership semantics***. They only ever *reference* data owned by another object.

> More importantly than the question posed, you might want to check that you keep around the buffer data long enough. A common pitfall is to pass a local as a buffer:
>
> ```
> std::string response = "OK\r\n\r\n";
> asio::async_write(sock_, asio::buffer(response), ...); // OOOPS!!!
> ```
>
> This leads to [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) immediately.

IOW `const_buffer` is a concept. There are a gazillion ways to construct it on top of (your own) objects:

> [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html)
>
> A buffer object represents a contiguous region of memory as a 2-tuple consisting of a pointer and size in bytes. A tuple of the form `{void*, size_t}` specifies a mutable (modifiable) region of memory. Similarly, a tuple of the form `{const void*, size_t}` specifies a const (non-modifiable) region of memory. These two forms correspond to the classes `mutable_buffer` and `const_buffer`, respectively

So, let's assume you have your buffer type

```
struct SecureBuffer
{
     ~SecureBuffer() { shred(); }
     size_t      size() const { return length_; }
     char const* data() const { return data_; }

     // ...
   private:
     void shred(); // uses SecureZeroMemory etc.

     std::array<char, 1024> data_ = {0};
     size_t length_ = 0u;
};
```

Then you can simply pass it where you want to use it:

```
SecureBuffer secret; // member variable (lifetime exceeds async operation)
// ... set data
boost::asio::async_write(sock_,
     boost::asio::buffer(secret.data(), secret.size()),
     /*...*/
    );
```